# Can't use Swift classes inside Objective-C unit test

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8, xctest

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206732/cant-use-swift-classes-inside-objective-c/27251979#27251979) recipe in order to use a Swift class in an existing Objective-C project `MyProject`. That works fine.

However, I'm still not able to use the same Swift class in the same project's unit tests. The compiler marks the line where my Objective-C unit test says `#import "MyProjectTests-Swift.h"` with `file not found`.

If tried changing the test target's `Product Module Name` from its default `MyProjectTests` to `MyProject` as suggested in a comment to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24367982/objective-c-test-class-using-swift-code) (unanswered) question. However the compiler now marks the line where my Objective-C unit test says `#import "MyProject-Swift.h"` with `file not found`.

So how can one integrate Swift classes into (XCTest) unit tests that are written in Objective-C? Does Apple provide any recipe?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24932147/how-should-a-swift-objective-c-project-be-setup-for-unit-testing ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As per @SushiGrassJacob's comment (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206732/cant-use-swift-classes-inside-objective-c/27251979#27251979)) the following solves the issue:

1. Make sure that Swift classes are targeted to both `MyProject` and  `MyProjectTest`.
2. In unit test, #import "MyProjectTests-Swift.h".

Comment: Thx! this was finally the answer I was searching for. Its really stupid to have to add Swift files to test target -.-

Comment: Adding files to the test target only works with a simple project with minimal imports. If your swift class inherits from an objc class then it will fail.

Answer (score 12):

### Step-1

Go to your test target > Build Settings > Header Search Paths, and add `$CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR/YourProject.build/DerivedSources` in it.

### Step-2

`#import "YourProject-Swift.h"`

Comment: This solved my problem. But good heavens how ever did you learn about this?

Answer (score 1):

Go to test target > Build Settings > Header Search Paths, and add $CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR/MyProject.build/DerivedSources in it. For me worked only without checking Swift classes targeted for MyProjectTests. Source: https://medium.com/if-let-swift-programming/ios-tests-working-with-objective-c-and-swift-class-together-aaf40f91a27c